# How can i switch between themes in jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my dropdown menu containing list of theme names.

boot.html

```
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Switch Theme<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>  <a>Dark</a>     </li>
                    <li>  <a>Apple</a>    </li>
                    <li>  <a>Blue</a>     </li>
                    <li>  <a>Pearl</a>    </li>
                    <li>  <a>Box</a>      </li>
                    <li>  <a>Pane</a>     </li>
                    <li>  <a>glue</a>     </li>
                    <li>  <a>Gun</a>      </li>
                    <li>  <a>Interim</a>  </li>
                    <li>  <a>Squash</a>   </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

If i click them i need the link tag point to different css file. I have found the solution that makes the link tag to point to  single css path when any of the list item is clicked in general. But i want different list to point out to different css path uniquely.

i have link tag paths for different themes like to file like

```
cssa/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssb/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssc/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssd/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
csse/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssf/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
```

Here is jquery solution that points to a path for any list item is clicked :

```
 <script>
 var link = $('link.me');

$(window).load(function () {
    var link = $('link.me');
     var list= $('ul.dropdown-menu li');
       list.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link.attr('href', 'cssh/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css')
    });

   });
</script>
```

I have to implement two things

1: I want each lists to point different paths. How can i implement it.

2: After refreshing, the page must stick to the selected theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Switch Theme<b class="caret"></b></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a data-theme="cssa/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Dark</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="csse/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Apple</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="cssb/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Blue</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="cssc/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Pearl</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="cssd/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Box</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Script

```
$(window).load(function () {
        var link = $('link.me');
       $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var theme = $(this).find('a').data('theme');
        var store = $(this).index();
        localStorage.setItem("colors", store);
        link.attr('href', theme)
       });
      var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('colors');
      if (retrievedObject != null) {
        $('ul.dropdown-menu li:eq(' + retrievedObject + ')').trigger('click');
      } else {
        $('ul.dropdown-menu li:eq(0)').click();
      }
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKM8/9/)

Comment: Thanks alot!! your solutions works like a charm. There is another problem if i refresh the page it defaults to older theme. How can i persist the change?

Comment: @DineshRavi I have answer are you opened question?

Comment: I have completed typing. But stackoverflow wants me to wait for 90 minutes. What should i do now.

Comment: @Here itself i updating check